# Cardinality of set of function

Tags: real-analysis

$A=\{f\in C^1[0,1]|f\left(0\right)=0,f\left(1\right)=1,|f'\left(t\right)|\leq 1~\forall~t\in [0,1]\}$ then cardinality of $A$, $|A|=1$

If we take $f\left(x\right)=x$ then $f\in A$.
Is this the only function in $A$?
I can not see that $A$ does not contain any functions other than $f$

Can someone give hint to prove $|A|=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otherwise, there exist $g \in A$ and $a \in (0,1)$ such that $g(a) > a$ or $g(a) < a$.

For the case $g(a) >a$,  by the mean-value theorem, we get $b \in (0,a)$ with $g'(b) = (g(a) - g(0)) / a > 1$, it is a contradiction.

For the case $g(a) <a$,  by the mean-value theorem, we get $b \in (a,1)$ with $g'(b) = (g(1) - g(a)) / 1 - a > 1$, it is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

If $0<a<1$, use the Mean Value Theorem on $[0,a]$ and on $[a,1]$ to arrive at contradictions if $f(a)>a$ or $f(a)<a$.